# How can I replacing space in between text in a list with a comma in python?

Tags: python, list, str-replace

I have a list as follows:

`a = ['viv', 'xyz', 'abc def']`

Now, I have to traverse through each element of the list and find out if any string is separated by a space in between and replace that space with a ','. So the output should look something similar to this:

`a = ['viv', 'xyz', 'abc.def']`

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; **asking us to write the program** for you, suggestions, and external links are **off-topic**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
def repl(a): 
    return [i.replace(" ", ",") for i in a]
```

Or iterate through the list:

```
def repl(a):
    end = []
    for i in a:
        end.append(i.replace(" ", ","))
    return end
```

In both cases:

```
>>> a = ['viv', 'xyz', 'abc def']
>>> repl(a)
['viv', 'xyz', 'abc,def']
```